# Access phppgadmin from another computer?

Tags: phppgadmin

I have installed phppgadmin in a Ubuntu server and want to access it from another computer.

It said access denied when i typed:

```
 http://<ip>/phppgadmin
```

The port 5432 is opened in the Ubuntu server but just for local ip.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **/etc/apache2/conf.d/phppgadmin.conf** configuration file by default keeps anyone but localhost from accessing PhpPgAdmin.

Add a line that makes a new allow rule for your IP, so it looks something like this:

```
<Location /phppgadmin>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from [Your client IP]
</Location>
```

---

By the way, this kind of question is probably more appropriate for stackoverflow's sister site [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: thanks for this answer. It saved me a lot of time :)
You deserve another up-vote...

Comment: You have to restart the apache server, Until you can not access the changes you have done

sudo service apache2 start

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but since i stumbled on it trying to fix the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" error while trying to access phpPgAdmin from another computer and the given answers didn't work for me, I wanted to share my solution.

Ubuntu: 17.04; phpPgAdmin: 5.1

Solution:
Comment out *Require local* in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phppgadmin.conf and restart apache (sudo service apache2 reload)

```
<Directory /usr/share/phppgadmin>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
AllowOverride None

# Only allow connections from localhost:
# Require local

<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
  php_flag track_vars On
  #php_value include_path .
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_php.c>
  <IfModule mod_actions.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phppgadmin.conf

Answer (score 3):

This is an apache (or web server) issue.  You're phppgadmin directory has a .htaccess file disallowing EVERYONE except localhost.

You need to either set it to Allow ALL or Allow (insert IP here)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Apache?

You need to change your permissions in the httpd.conf file or .htaccess

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my solution as well.

Debian 10.1 with Apache 2.4.38 and phpPgAdmin 5.1 on 64-Bit ARM.

The following config will allow local and LAN access, but (for security reasons) NO WAN access.

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phppgadmin.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phppgadmin>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
AllowOverride None

# Only allow connections from localhost:
#Require local
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.0.0/16
Allow from 172.16.0.0/12
Allow from 10.0.0.0/8

<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
  php_flag track_vars On
  #php_value include_path .
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_php.c>
  <IfModule mod_actions.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
      Action application/x-httpd-php /cgi-bin/php
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

</Directory>
```